# Wordpress conditional category php loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm working on a website, and I was wondering if it's possible to have a loop that shows related posts (in a sidebar or somewhere else), but only if there are any related posts matching the criteria.

For instance: I'm reading a page about lightning, the sidebar should show all the posts in the category "thiscategory"(lightning in this case) AND "whitepaper"(always fixed).

I've tried the following loop, but it gives me a syntax error:

```
     <!-- Start the Loop. -->

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if ( ! in_category('whitepaper') ) { ?>

        <!-- don't display anything if it's nog in category whitepaper -->

        <?php } else { 

        $mycat = get_the_category;

        if ( in_category( $mycat ) { ?>
        bla
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the syntax error? This selection statement is `iff ( ! in_category('whitepaper') )` is pointless as you're not doing anything with it, plus you should always use true conditions as the first if and false conditions as the else part. Here's your code cleaned up: http://pastie.org/3335622

Comment: Also, for the sake of readability, please use indents and new lines to lay out the code... this is particularly true when you're using `endwhile` and `endif` syntax rather than braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use query_posts().

```
<?php 
//Grab the two category ID you are interested in.
$white_paper = get_cat_ID( 'whitepaper' ); 
$curr_cat = get_query_var('cat');

//Query posts for the categories you want
query_posts("cat=$white_paper,$curr_cat");

//Now loop as normal
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```